# How to change the url dinamically when redirecting on click? React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, react-router, query-string

How to **dinamically** change the url? This url 'www.example.com' is changing depending on where i use it as you can see it below, also the query string is changing depending on the component and on the card-id.

Here is simple example of my code:

```
return (
props.news.map((content, index) =>
<NewsCard 
key={index}
title={content.title}
text={content.text}
onClick={() => {
location.href = 'www.example-news.com/?a=query';
}}
/>
<JurnalistCard
key={index}
person={content.person}
name={content.name}
onClick={() => {
location.href = 'www.example-jurnaist.com/?a=query';
}}/>
))
```

Json file:

```
export const news: News[] = [
  {
        title: 'Title1',
        text: 'Text test',
        queryString1: 'queryString',
        queryString2: 'queryString',
        person: 'Full Name',
        name: 'John'
  },
 {
        title: 'Title1',
        text: 'Text test',
        queryString1: 'queryString',
        queryString2: 'queryString',
        person: 'Full Name',
        name: 'John'
  },
 {
        title: 'Title1',
        text: 'Text test',
        queryString1: 'queryString',
        queryString2: 'queryString',
        person: 'Full Name',
        name: 'John'
  }
]
```

I am new in React, please help.

Comment: `location.href` or `location.replace` should work. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location). What's not working in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the url in props and do something like this

```
return (
    props.news.map((content, index) =>
    <NewsCard 
        key={index}
        title={content.title}
        text-{content.text}
        onClick={() => {
            location.href = content.newsUrl;
        }}
     />
     <JurnalistCard
         key={index}
         person={content.person}
         name={content.name}
         onClick={() => {
             location.href = content.journalistUrl;
     }}/>
 ))
```

If you can't store the url in props and you use other values to form the query, you could structure it like this:

```
{"'www.example-news.com/?a=" + content.title}
```

Comment: i have tried this but it isnt reading the journalistUrl from the json, content is read but after the dot journalistUrl is giving any and not returning the string.

Comment: What does you json file look like?

Comment: It probably isn't anything to do with json. Try window.location.href

Comment: I added the json in the description

Comment: I solved this. I dont know why but it was working only if it was in backticks `${content.journalistUrl}` and not if it was like this {content.journalistUrl}

Comment: That makes sense. After looking at it again you don't need the {} around content.journalistUrl. Remove it and it should work